# Measure time for rendering ListView

Tags: android, performance, list

How can I measure time that ListView/ListActivity takes for rendering its list?

I have a ListActivity that takes a long time to show (on older devices it's ~3s) and I'd like to optimize that.

EDIT:

I already have time between Activity1 and Activity2. During this time, Activity2 is doing some stuff (initializing). Among other things, it renders its list. I want to get time this activity takes to render that list. If total time between activities is 3s, I want to know whether rendering list takes 2.9s or 0.5s....

Answer (score 3):

You could simply ouput the time. For example you could use the logcat

```
final long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

// code to measure

Log.w(TAG, "TEXT" + System.currentTimeMillis()-t0);
```

Of course you could use any other system for the ouput like a dialog or stuff. Just use what you like.

EDIT:

If you don't want to use a debug message in your code all the time you could do it like this:

Create a class called settings:

```
public class Settings {
public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
// If you prefer you could do use an enum
// enum debugLevel {SHOW_EVERYMESSAGE, ERRORS, IMPORTANT_MESSAGES, ...}
// In your classes you would have to check that DEBUG is less or equal than
// the debugLevel you want 
}
```

In classes where you want to use a debug message simply do this

```
import xxx.yyy.Settings

class foo {
  final static boolean DEBUG = Settings.DEBUG;
  if(DEBUG){
    // Debug messages
  }
}
```

Now if you want to disable DEBUG messages you could simply set `DEBUG = false` in your Settings class.

If you want to measure between two activities you could use intents and send t0 with an intent to the other activity to compute the time. Of course you could include this with `if(DEBUG){ /* code */ }` statements to spare the sending of the intent in the final release. The if statements should not increase the computation of your code too dramatically.

Comment: Yes, but at what point? Is there something like onStartRender/onStoprender?

Comment: I have a gap between onPause of the previous and onResume of the ListActivity. And I wouldn't put a debug line in adapter's getView...

Comment: Use an intent to send t0 between the two activities. Or use my edited solution. With this you could almost remove debug messages before releasing your code without too much hassle.

Comment: I think you don't understand me.. I already have time between Activity1 and Activity2. During this time, Activity2 is doing some stuff. Among other things, it renders its list. I want to get time this activity takes to render that list. If total time between activities is 3s, I want to know if rendering list takes 2.9s, or if it takes 0.5s....

Comment: If you really think it is the rendering, get the ListView.java from the android source and put it into your project. Then insert debug messages and `import` that ListView.java instead of the `android.widget.ListView`. But first i would try to find out, how long it takes to fill the list elements with data. As i would think, this is the bottleneck in a long list. How do you populate your list? Do you always open a database? Or do you save the data after the first call to the database? Opening a database could take long.

Comment: I obtain ArrayList of objects in onCreate/onResume and update that list from some listener. That list is provided to a custom list adapter. In the meanwhile i put a Log.d in getView of the adapter, and found out that rendering list takes about 2sec. Each item takes 30-50ms to render. I'm not sure if I can make that much better...

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell if Java offers a better implementation using `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `System.nanoTime()`. Nevertheless, you should give the [TimingLogger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger.html) class a try. Take a look at this [article describing the usage of the TimingLogger helper class](http://hoccer.com/2010/09/measuring-performance-with-android/).